# Session value doesnt pass on to the next page

Tags: php

Basically I want to grab an id send via the url (ex. www.website.com/?id=432432) and take it accross my website till the user hits the contact page. I created a variable and a session variable

```
session_start();
$getId = $_GET["id"];
$_SESSION['session_browser_test'] = $getId;
$adv_id = $_SESSION['session_browser_test'];
```

and used

```
echo $adv_id;
```

on my index.php Joomla template so it applies to all the pages.

But the issue is when i go to www.website.com/?id=432432 it echos the id on my web page, but if I click on the next link to go to another page (ex. www.website.com/nextPage)  it doesnt hold the session value from the previous page.  Why is that? and how can I carry the ID through out the site?

Comment: Did you do `session_start()` ?

Comment: Yes, I did. Sorry forgot to mention.

Comment: did _you_ turned _off_ cookies? (sry)

Comment: @TheHe No i didnt touch cookies.

Comment: did you enabled error_reporting, display_errors and display_startup_errors (not in mind if that is the correct key)...
is the php-installation 100% working with sessions? maybe it can't persist the session-data.

Comment: AH! do you set the id on EVERY test page?!?
if you don't provide the id in query-variables it will be EMPTY.. so you overwrite the id...

if(!empty($_GET['id'])) $_SESSION['foobar'] = (int)$_GET['id'];
echo $_SESSION['foobar'];

Comment: @TheHe : Thats it man. This is what I did. 

 if(isset($_GET["adv_id"])){
  $_SESSION['session_browser_test2'] = $_GET["adv_id"];
  $adv_id = $_SESSION['session_browser_test2'];
 
 }else{
  $adv_id = $_SESSION['session_browser_test2'];
 }

Comment: and that will not work!?

Comment: @TheHe : That is man = Yeah it worked. :) thanks heaps for the idea man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(isset($_GET["adv_id"])){ 
  $_SESSION['session_browser_test2'] = $_GET["adv_id"];
  $adv_id = $_SESSION['session_browser_test2'];
}
else {
  $adv_id = $_SESSION['session_browser_test2'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you will not get an id from URL on next page, likely

```
echo $getId;
```

instead you need to use id from session like,

```
$_SESSION['session_browser_test']; // your id stored in session
```

Comment: Im trying to do the exact same thing as you are saying. But it doesnt show up.

Answer (score 1):

Start the session in each page

```
 session_start();
```

In order to access the variable in a session, you have to call the $_SESSION variable.

```
echo $_SESSION['session_browser_test'];
```

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is stateless, so you have to do something to remember your variable throughout the website . 
make sure you correctly use session , like session_start();
when you send your id through get method ,it works, but when you go to any other page ,it doesn't make any sense to remember this.
use this for send id through pages:

```
<?php echo get_permalink(910); ?>?userid=<?php echo $value['userId'];?>
```

send this in url and use on next page as:

```
$sql = "select * from `wp_pelleresuser` where userId =".$_GET['userid'];
```

using this approach you can use a single variable on every page you want without using session. try google to how wordpress manage variable through all pages without using session. it will help you.
happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Start

```
session_start();
```

(if not started) in the index.php in root of your app (session probably will start on every pages) and then call (when desired):

```
$_SESSION['session_browser_test'];
```

instead of assi8gning this sess var to your own variable and then calling it in different places.